# Use greater_equal in adjacent_find to find equivalent elements in sorted sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, c++20

Is it UB to use `std::greater_equal` in `std::adjacent_find` algorithm to find equivalent (as opposite to equal) elements in sorted range?

The answer can be "no" if order of *prev* and *next* elements in `std::greater_equal<>{}(*prev, *next)` inside of implementation of the algorithm is not specified strictly.

```
std::container<int> c{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
assert(std::is_sorted(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c));
assert(std::adjacent_find(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c), std::greater_equal<int>{}) != std::cend(c));
```

Comment: FWIW, [here's the general BinaryPredicate reqs](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::adjacent_find` searches for two consecutive elements where the predicate returns `true`. The [C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.adjacent.find) documents the behavior as finding:

- `*i == *(i + 1)` for the overloads with no parameter `pred`
- `pred(*i, *(i + 1)) != false` for the overloads with a parameter `pred`

The second bullet specifies the order that the elements are passed to the predicate.

This example implementation ([copied from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)) should make this clearer.

```
template<class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt adjacent_find(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p)
{
    if (first == last) {
        return last;
    }
    ForwardIt next = first;
    ++next;
    for (; next != last; ++next, ++first) {
        if (p(*first, *next)) { // <- predicate called here
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it UB to use std::less in std::adjacent_find algorithm to find
>   equivalent (as opposite to equal) elements in sorted range?

It is never undefined behaviour, the only restrictions for predicate passed to `std::adjacent_find` are proper type and not modyfing its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this template:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt adjacent_find( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p );
```

Here `p` is

> p     -   binary predicate which returns ​true if the elements should be treated as equal.

There is no UB here as long as the requirements of the algorithm are met. If for your problem you have to treat `less` as `equal` then it's perfectly valid.

Comment: But what about commutativity requirement?

Comment: @Orient Commutative property is for example is `a + b = b  + a.` Generalize that, `a some_operation b = b some_operation a`. Essentially the algorithm says, find an adjacent pair that makes the predicate `p` true. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `a = b` <=> `b = a`.

Comment: @Orient well `if a < b` doesn't imply `b < a` cause it could be the case that `b == a`. Does that answer your question? in your example is `std::greater` and `std::less` what you want. Can you be more specific? I understand you need `simmetry` but `where`

Comment: @KostasRim, What's meant is that the default predicate obeys this rule, but this new predicate does not. This can easily give you problems elsewhere like sorting; failing to meet semantic requirements leads to UB and the OP is wondering if changing these semantics actually violates any requirement.

Comment: @chris that wasn't very clear, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have UB, but it is not `std::less` that you want, as `1 < 2`, it would return iterator to `1`.

You need:

```
std::vector<int> c{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
assert(std::is_sorted(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c));
auto it = std::adjacent_find(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c),
                             [](auto lhs, auto rhs){
                                 // For unsorted container, you would need
                                 // return !(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs);
                                 // but as container is sorted,
                                 // we already have (lhs < rhs) || !(rhs < lhs)
                                 return !(lhs < rhs);

                             });
// *it == 3; *(it+1) == 3;
```